# How to make DataTable, but the row is only appended

Tags: javascript, html-table, datatables

I have a table that add rows manually, but I want to make it into a DataTable to make it friendly user. But I don't know how to do it.

I tried to search it online and I see this, it is similar but it is not working or I'm doing something wrong... [See here](https://datatables.net/examples/api/add_row.html#:%7E:text=New%20rows%20can%20be%20added,be%20added%20using%20the%20rows.)

Also this is my code :

```js
const tbody = document.getElementById("choicesListTbodyADD");
const btnAdd = document.querySelector("button");
const inputChoices = document.querySelector("input");
var count = 1;
btnAdd.addEventListener("click", function () {
  $(tbody).append(`<tr><td>${count}</td><td>${inputChoices.value.trim()}</td><td>DELETE</td></tr>`)
  inputChoices.value = '';
})
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<br><br>
<input type="text" id="choices"/>
<button id="appendChoices">Add Choices</button>
<br><br>

<table class="table text-center table-bordered table-striped dataTable dtr-inline" id="ADDchoicesARTableListSequence">
  <tr>
    <th>No.</th>
    <th>Choices</th>
    <th>Action</th>
  </tr>
  <tbody id="choicesListTbodyADD"></tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: The DataTables function `row.add()` is a good approach - but you are not using it in the code you have shown us. Show us your actual attempt to use it - even if that attempt failed. It may also help if you start by visiting the [download page](https://datatables.net/download/index), since it looks as if you want to combine DataTables with Bootstrap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an approach, based on your non-DataTables code.

I have included the Bootstrap libraries I think you need - but you can adjust those if needed.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var table = $('#ADDchoicesARTableListSequence').DataTable();

  const tbody = document.getElementById("choicesListTbodyADD");
  const btnAdd = document.querySelector("button");
  const inputChoices = document.querySelector("input");
  var count = 1;
  btnAdd.addEventListener("click", function() {
    table.row.add($(`<tr><td>${count}</td><td>${inputChoices.value.trim()}</td><td>DELETE</td></tr>`)).draw();
    count += 1;
    inputChoices.value = '';
  })

});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Demo</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/5.1.3/css/bootstrap.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.1/css/dataTables.bootstrap5.css" />

  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/5.1.3/js/bootstrap.bundle.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.1/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.1/js/dataTables.bootstrap5.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

  <div style="margin: 20px;">
    <input type="text" id="choices" />
    <button id="appendChoices">Add Choices</button>
    <br><br>

    <table class="table text-center table-bordered table-striped dataTable dtr-inline" id="ADDchoicesARTableListSequence">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>No.</th>
          <th>Choices</th>
          <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
    </table>

  </div>



</body>

</html>
```

The main points to note:

1. Your HTML table does not need a `<body>` in this case, as DataTables will provide it for you.
2. Don't forget to use `draw()` after adding each row - to re-draw the table, so the new data is displayed.
3. In this case, I create a new DOM node from your data using `$(<tr>...</tr>)`. But you can see from the [documentation](https://datatables.net/reference/api/row.add()) that there are other ways you can create new rows:

- using an array
- using an object
- using a node (which is what we do here)

I chose to use a node because that is the closest to what your code already does.

Comment: It's working properly in codepen. but when i paste it into my code editor. it gives me an error DataTables warning: table id=ADDchoicesARTableListSequence - Requested unknown parameter '1' for row 0, column 1. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/4. does it matter the version? i think i'm using the lower version because of the theme im using

Comment: I copied the exact code tho i change the inputs ID and buttons.. but it throwing an error..

Comment: OK - understood.  My suggestion: Add a new runnable demo to your question - one which throws the error you are getting. It's difficult to debug an issue for you, here on Stack Overflow, if we cannot recreate that issue. Your demo can show _exactly_ what versions you are using, for every library. If you made changes to the versions (if they are different from the ones in my answer), then maybe that is the problem - or maybe the problem is something completely different.

Comment: Also, make sure you have studied the "resolution" section of the [error message](https://datatables.net/manual/tech-notes/4#Resolution) - and report your findings to us. You can ask a new question, if that is easier.